# Editing code which shows three balls moving from one site to another

Tags: graphics, animation

I would like to have your help in editing the following Mathematical code.

The code shown below represents applying translation to three balls aligned vertically at one site. I want to edit it so it will instead show two balls setting at one site and the third ball setting on the site next to the site of the first two.

```
g =
  With[
    {baseline = -2.5 {0, 1, 2, 3}, 
     t = Range[-2, 2, 0.01], 
     tdots = {-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5}},
    Module[{s, dots, hop},
      s = Cos[2 π t];
      dots[k_] :=
        With[
          {td = tdots[[k]], 
           y0 = baseline[[k]] + 0.15, dy = 0.4, 
           r = 0.16}, 
          {Red, Disk[{td, y0 + dy}, r], Disk[{td, y0}, r], Disk[{td, y0 - dy}, r]}];
      hop[k1_, k2_] :=
        With[
          {y = baseline[[k1]] + 1, 
           t1 = tdots[[k1]], 
           t2 = tdots[[k2]]},
          Arrow[
            BezierCurve[
              {{t1, y}, {0.9 t1 + 0.1 t2, y + 0.5}, 
               {0.1 t1 + 0.9 t2, y + 0.5}, {t2, y}}]]];
      Graphics[
        {Table[Line @ Thread@{t, s + baseline[[k]]}, {k, 1, 4}],
         Table[dots[k], {k, 1, 4}],
         hop[1, 2], hop[2, 3], hop[3, 4], hop[4, 1]}]]]
```

which produces

[image: code result]

Comment: So you want to go from "three balls in one trough" to "two balls in one trough and one ball in the neighboring trough", then move around the sine wave?

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. yes right

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question before today...

Answer (score 7):

```
With[{baseline = -2.5 {0, 1, 2, 3}, t = Range[-2, 3, 0.01]}, 
 Module[{s}, s = Cos[2 Pi t];
  Graphics[{Table[Line@Thread@{t, s + baseline[[k]]}, {k, 1, 4}]}]]]

With[{baseline = -2.5 {0, 1, 2, 3}, t = Range[-2, 3, 0.01], 
  tdots = {-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5}}, 
 Module[{s, dots}, s = Cos[2 \[Pi] t];
  dots[k_] := 
   With[{td = tdots[[k]], y0 = baseline[[k]] + 0.15, dy = 0.4, 
     r = 0.16}, {Red, Disk[{td + 1, y0 - dy}, r], 
     Disk[{td, y0}, r], Disk[{td, y0 - dy}, r]}];
  Graphics[{Table[Line@Thread@{t, s + baseline[[k]]}, {k, 1, 4}], 
    Table[dots[k], {k, 1, 4}]}]]]

g = With[{baseline = -2.5 {0, 1, 2, 3}, t = Range[-2, 3, 0.01], 
   tdots = {-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5}}, 
  Module[{s, dots, hop}, s = Cos[2 \[Pi] t];
   dots[k_] := 
    With[{td = tdots[[k]], y0 = baseline[[k]] + 0.15, dy = 0.4, 
      r = 0.16}, {Red, Disk[{td + 1, y0 - dy}, r], 
      Disk[{td, y0}, r], Disk[{td, y0 - dy}, r]}];
   hop[k1_, k2_] := 
    With[{y = baseline[[k1]] + 1, t1 = tdots[[k1]], t2 = tdots[[k2]]},
      Arrow[
      BezierCurve[{{t1, y}, {0.9 t1 + 0.1 t2, 
         y + 0.5}, {0.1 t1 + 0.9 t2, y + 0.5}, {t2, y}}]]];
   Graphics[{Table[Line@Thread@{t, s + baseline[[k]]}, {k, 1, 4}], 
     Table[dots[k], {k, 1, 4}], hop[1, 2], hop[2, 3], hop[3, 4], 
     hop[4, 1]}]]]
```

[image: fig1]

After the discussion a second variant of the solution of the problem arose

```
With[{baseline = -2.5 {0, 1, 2, 3}, t = Range[-2, 2, 0.01]}, 
 Module[{s}, s = Cos[2 Pi t];
  Graphics[{Table[Line@Thread@{t, s + baseline[[k]]}, {k, 1, 4}]}]]]

With[{baseline = -2.5 {0, 1, 2, 3}, t = Range[-2, 2, 0.01], 
  tdots = {-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, -1.5}}, 
 Module[{s, dots}, s = Cos[2 \[Pi] t];
  dots[k_] := 
   With[{td = tdots[[k]], td1 = tdots[[k + 1]], 
     y0 = baseline[[k]] + 0.15, dy = 0.4, r = 0.16}, {Red, 
     Disk[{td1, y0 - dy}, r], Disk[{td, y0}, r], 
     Disk[{td, y0 - dy}, r]}];
  Graphics[{Table[Line@Thread@{t, s + baseline[[k]]}, {k, 1, 4}], 
    Table[dots[k], {k, 1, 4}]}]]]

g = With[{baseline = -2.5 {0, 1, 2, 3}, t = Range[-2, 2, 0.01], 
   tdots = {-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, -1.5}}, 
  Module[{s, dots, hop}, s = Cos[2 \[Pi] t];
   dots[k_] := 
    With[{td = tdots[[k]], td1 = tdots[[k + 1]], 
      y0 = baseline[[k]] + 0.15, dy = 0.4, r = 0.16}, {Red, 
      Disk[{td1, y0 - dy}, r], Disk[{td, y0}, r], 
      Disk[{td, y0 - dy}, r]}];
   hop[k1_, k2_] := 
    With[{y = baseline[[k1]] + 1, t1 = tdots[[k1 + 1]], 
      t2 = tdots[[k2 + 1]]}, 
     Arrow[BezierCurve[{{t1, y}, {0.9 t1 + 0.1 t2, 
         y + 0.5}, {0.1 t1 + 0.9 t2, y + 0.5}, {t2, y}}]]];
   Graphics[{Table[Line@Thread@{t, s + baseline[[k]]}, {k, 1, 4}], 
     Table[dots[k], {k, 1, 4}], hop[2, 3], hop[3, 4], hop[4, 1], 
     hop[1, 2]}]]]
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: thank you very much !

Comment: Trounev I need four sites not five site and the fourth case should be a ball on the first site and the other two balls in the fourth site , ( like periodic boundary condition ) and the arrow should point to the empty site , can you fix it so I would get that , I would be so so thankful it will help me so much , thanks

Comment: @maya I did not catch the last thought. Where should the arrow be shown, on which empty site?

Comment: ,the next empty site . for example in the first scheme  the arrow should point to the third site

Comment: @maya I added a new code. Can you explain to me what these drawings are for?

Comment: thank you very much! , I need these drawings  for a project in physics , I want to describe applying transnational operator on fock states , fock states describe the number of states for N particles sitting on M sites , when we apply transitional operator on specific fock state it cause the particles to move to the neighbor site

Comment: @maya Thank you, now I see the point.